# Navigate to new component after dispatch from mapDispatchToProps

Tags: react-native, redux

After setting the language for my app by clicking the English or French button, I need to navigate to the next screen. How do I call `this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')` directly after a `dispatch`?

I tried putting both in a function and calling it from `onPress`, but that didn't work.

**LanguageScreen.js**

```
<Button
 title="English"
 onPress={this.props.english}
 />
 <Button
 title="Français"
 onPress={this.props.french}
 />
```

**LanguageContainer.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LanguageScreen from '../screens/LanguageScreen.js';

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  language: state.language
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  french: () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FRENCH' });
  },
  english: () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ENGLISH' });
  },
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LanguageScreen)
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

export const language = (state = 'english', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'FRENCH':
    return 'french';
  case 'ENGLISH':
    return 'english';
  default:
    return state;
  }
}

let store = createStore(language);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 2):

`mapDispatchToProps` accepts `ownProps` as second argument so assuming your component receives `navigate` prop you can try something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  french: () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FRENCH' });
    ownProps.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
  },
  english: () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ENGLISH' });
    ownProps.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
  },
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Do I have to make any changes other than what you have shown?

Comment: Can you show how do you use `LanguageContainer` component in your application? Are you sure that  this component receives `navigation` property? Are there any errors?